# Why is the code after the if statement executed 3 times?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm no coder, but I'm trying to learn.
I've got this code snippet that I'm expecting to write the output only once in the resses.txt file, but instead it writes it 3 times. Please note, that I'm always clearing my cookies in my browser before trying this. (I simulate a user that has never been on my site before).
Can you also please explain to me this behavior?

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height'])){
    $ress = $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];
} else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
    $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
}

$file = fopen("resses.txt", "a");
$ressescontent = "screen resolution is
$ress
";
fputs ($file, "###############\r\n");
fputs ($file, "$ressescontent\r\n");
fclose ($file);

?>
```

So instead of this

```
###############
screen resolution is
1280x1024
```

I'm getting this:

```
###############
screen resolution is


###############
screen resolution is


###############
screen resolution is
1280x1024
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file write code is outside of the `if statement` you should take it inside.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height'])){
    $ress = $_SESSION['screen_width'] . 'x' . $_SESSION['screen_height'];    
    $file = fopen("resses.txt", "a");
    $ressescontent = "screen resolution is $ress";
    fputs ($file, "###############\r\n");
    fputs ($file, "$ressescontent\r\n");
    fclose ($file);

} else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
    $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Well, I should mention, that this answer making code more transparent and obvious, than mine. ++

Comment: Thanks. I see, now. But if I wanted to add some code after the IF-statement, how do I go about preventing this problem from repeating. I'm not sure I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answer are correct.  but may not help you understand why.

The issue you have is that the whole script will be run every time.  So on the first pass through there is nothing in the session and `$_REQUEST` variable is empty so the javascript will fire to redirect the page.  The php script caries on running so the file will be opened and written to with no height or width information.

The browser will execute the javascript redirect.  Brining us in to a second pass through the php script.  This time the `$_REQUEST` variable is set, but there is still nothing in the session so this time through the session details will be set and the header is sent to redirect the page, but the php script caries on running so the file will be opened and written to with no height or width information.

The browser will react to the header and redirect to the page again.  Bring us to the third pass through.  This time the `$_REQUEST` variable is empty, but the session has some data in it.  So the `$ress` variable is then set and when the file is open and written to it has the correct data in it.

HAL9000's solution or Rikesh's are both viable, but I prefer Rikesh's to put the file writing inside the if statement as it makes for more easily understandable code.

Comment: So there's no way of adding code after the IF-statement without it repeating itself 3 times?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to use the approach suggested by HAL9000 and use the exit to stop the script after the redirects.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find HAL9000 suggestion.

Comment: That is because he has now removed it.  The basic premise of his solution is to add an `exit();` statement after each of the redirects.  This will have the effect of immediately terminating the script at that line without executing anything else.